# login page not redirect to reports page in asp.net mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, redirect

i try to login with usertype and redirect to their pages e.g admin redirect to reports page and public user redirect to gallery..

when i try to login from admin username and password then nothing happened.. when click on login button page redirect login page and not redirect to reports page where as i want when admin login then they redirect to reports page

whereas when i login with public user name and password it redirect to gallery pages ..

here is the code

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      name = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
      pwd = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
      conn.Open();
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select ln.UName, ln.UPasword, ut.UserType_ID from login ln, UserType ut where ln.UName = '" 
              + name + "' and ln.UPasword = '" + pwd 
              + "' and ln.UserType_ID = ut.UserType_ID");
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if ( dr.HasRows )
      {
         dr.Read( );
         Session[ " UName" ] = dr[ 0 ].ToString( );
         Session[ " UPasword" ] = dr[ 1 ].ToString( );
         Session[ "UserType_ID" ] = dr[ 2 ].ToString( );
      }    
      if (dr[2].ToString() == "1")
      {
           Response.Redirect( "View_Reports.aspx" );
      }
      else
      {
         Response.Redirect( "gallery.aspx" );
      }

      dr.Close();
      conn.Close();
  }
```

any help please?

Comment: is space is intentional or by imstake ` Session[ " UName" ]`

Comment: intentional...........

Comment: when i remove spaces problem is not resolved

Answer (score 0):

As from you question it is clear that it is not going in if part.
Check the `dr[2].ToString()` value in your code are you getting "1" for not.
You have also not used `try`,`catch` and `finally` block in you code. Use them.